# Summation involving Hermite polynomials.

Tags: real-analysis, summation

I am wondering how to calculate the following summation
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^j}{j!\sqrt{2^j}}H_j(x),$$
where $H_j(x)$ are the Hermite polynomials. I thought that we could use the generating function for Hermite polynomials, namely
$$\exp(2xt-t^2)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}H_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!},$$
but I haven't been able to find the value of the series.

Comment: I wonder if you have tried plugging $t = e/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you!